# How to recalculate checksums without re-running the statements in liquibase?

Tags: liquibase, checksum, changelog, liquibase-sql

We were upgrade our liquibase from 1.9.0.0 to 3.6.3. When running migration MD5SUM for 3.6.3 was updated but it was trying to re-run the previously executed changesets which were executed with liquibase 1.9.0.0. How do i run only updating checksum with without re-running the statements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase has [Command Line Interface](https://docsstage.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/cli/home.html). And the CLI has [clearCheckSums](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/clearchecksums.html) command.

> clearCheckSums clears all checksums and nullifies the MD5SUM column of
> the DATABASECHANGELOG table so they will be re-computed on the next
> database update.
>
> changesets that have been deployed will have their checksums
> re-computed, and pending changesets will be deployed.

Comment: If i clear checksums. it will re run all statements again right?

Comment: It will not rerun the changeSets which were already executed. If some of the changeSets weren't executed, then these changeSets will be executed.

Comment: Thanks @htshame. You given me a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a link to the answer on [liquibase forums](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/how-to-recalculate-checksums-without-re-running-the-statements-in-liquibase/5226?u=rakhi) for other users if they encounter the same query ever in future.